# Passing address of public variable

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe, ref

When i try to pass the address of a public variable like this:

```
ML.Register("Radius", &lBeacons[i].Radius, 0.0f, 200.0f, 10.0f);
```

I get this error:

```
error CS0212: You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer
```

The Register function looks like this:

```
public unsafe void Register(string desc, float* val, float minimum, float maximum, float stepsize)
```

Beacons is a List. It holds a class with the Public Radius.

Comment: I summon Jon Skeet! The whole pointers-references-classes-and-structs-in-csharp thing is his favourite subject.

Comment: Re your comment "i want to store the address of Radius (and others) in ML for future things" - No! don't do it! .NET objects move around; you cannot rely on a pointer outside of a fixed block (which should be short-lived). Pass the Radius object (reference) into ML, and update properties of the Radius object.

Answer (score 8):

Would it not make sense just to pass the value by reference?

```
public void Register(string desc, ref float val, float minimum,
         float maximum, float stepsize) {...}
```

Of course, using public variables (fields) is a bad idea too... it would work like so:

```
ML.Register("Radius", ref lBeacons[i].Radius, 0.0f, 200.0f, 10.0f);
```

But it *won't* work if you make `Radius` a property - so don't do this. Consider passing the beacon (or similar) itself, or some other object-based (or maybe event-based) mechanism.

---

something like:

```
ML.Register("Radius", lBeacons[i], 0.0f, 200.0f, 10.0f);
```

with:

```
private Beacon beacon;
public void Register(string desc, Beacon beacon, float minimum,
         float maximum, float stepsize) {
    this.beacon = beacon;
}
void Foo() {
    beacon.Radius++; // etc
}
```

Here we have a *reference* to the Beacon object, which doesn't have the `unsafe` issues of pointers. If you don't want to expose the `Beacon` directly, consider using an interface.

Comment: just cannot compete against a guy with your rep score...:)

Answer (score 4):

To get a pointer to a variable, use the fixed keyword to pin it in place, like:

```
fixed(float *radius=&lBeacons[i].Radius)
{
  ML.Register("Radius", radius, 0.0f, 200.0f, 10.0f);
}
```

The method this gets placed in needs to be declared as unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

Why use pointers?  You can just use the "ref" keyword to pass a reference of the variable.

example:

```
object blah = new object();

CallMethod(ref blah);


public void CallMethod(ref object param)
{

}
```

Comment: Yes, i forgot the mention i want to store the address of Radius (and others) in ML for future things... Thats why i use pointers (and my C++ thinking)

Comment: This could be slightly to the OP, because now you are passing, by reference, a reference to a boxed copy of the variable - which isn't the same as passing a reference to the variable itself...

Comment: Are you saying that because I am using a reference type instead of a value type..sorry got confused?

Comment: I think I know what you are saying, and I was just trying to show the passing of references..guess I could have been more concise to this example....need to work on the wording of my answers :)

Comment: It is tricky, because there is "passing a reference" and "passing by reference" - and all 4 permutations are valid.

Comment: completely understand what you are saying....and I was just using a generic example to show the "ref".  Completely understand what you mean though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a fixed block.

```
fixed(float *rad = &(lBeacons[i].Radius))) {
    ML.Register("Radius", rad, 0f, 200f, 10f);
}
```

I don't think you want to do this in any case.  If ML uses rad outside of the fixed block, it is likely to fail.  I think you're better off rethinking your API.

Comment: I doubt that would work. You are getting the address of the copied valuetype, I think.